# How to match Scribunto version with Wikibase container version?

Tags: mediawiki-extensions, wikibase

I am running a Wikibase using the docker images explained [here](https://github.com/wmde/wikibase-docker). However, after install, I would like to use the SPARQL2 template used in Wikidata, which I try to migrate using Special:Export (on Wikidata) and Special:Import (on local wikibase). This seems to work, but the import chokes on the Scribuntu mediawiki extension missing. After following the install instructions, I get the following message.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Scribunto is not compatible with the current MediaWiki core (version 1.30.0), it requires: >=1.31.0. in /var/www/html/includes/registration/ExtensionRegistry.php:261 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/includes/registration/ExtensionRegistry.php(148): ExtensionRegistry->readFromQueue(Array) #1 /var/www/html/includes/Setup.php(40): ExtensionRegistry->loadFromQueue() #2 /var/www/html/includes/WebStart.php(114): require_once('/var/www/html/i...') #3 /var/www/html/index.php(40): require('/var/www/html/i...') #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/includes/registration/ExtensionRegistry.php on line 261

How do upgrade from version 1.30 to version 1.31 or higher? Can this be done from with in the running docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download a version of Scribunto that matches the version of Mediawiki / Wikibase that you are running.

The current latest tags of the Wikibase docker image are for Mediawiki 1.30 as can be seen at https://hub.docker.com/r/wikibase/wikibase/tags/

You must have downloaded either master or 1.31 of Scribunto.

To get 1.30 you can either:

- Use the git branch REL1_30
  https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Scribunto/tree/REL1_30
- Select the 1.30 version from the Extension Distributor https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ExtensionDistributor/Scribunto